# How to throw an error during a parameter check without if-statements in Google-Earth-Engine?

Tags: throw, google-earth-engine

I am working on a new version of the [`bfast monitor` algorithm in Google Earth Engine](https://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/12/18/2953). See the code of the original algorithm on [Github](https://github.com/bfast2/geeBfastMonitor/blob/master/monitor.js).
The function `bfastMonitor()` takes user-defined parameters and applies some parameter checks before starting actual calculations. When the user-defined parameter settings are incompatible with the algorithm, an error should be raised.

During the parameter check, two types of if statements are made: statements that only check the parameter boundaries and raise an error at incompatible values, and statements that check and rewrite the contents of a parameter and raise an error at incompatible values. For the sake of the focus of this question, I will consider only the latter one.

Obviously, in a conventional coding paradigm, if-statements can be used to do this parameter check, however, [using if-statements goes against the client-server model of GEE](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/best_practices#avoid-ee.algorithms.if).

Consider the `period` parameter, which can only be 2,4,6,8, or 10. This parameter code used to index a list later in the code (line 459 on Github), where a `period`-value of `4` means that the list should be indexed at position `1`, for instance.

Currently the implementation looks like this, using if-statements:

```js
period = period||10

if (period == 2) {
   period  = 0;
} else if (period  == 4){
   period  = 1;
}else if (period  == 6){
   period  = 2;
}else if (period  == 8){
   period  = 3;
}else if (period  == 10){
   period  = 4;
}else {
  alert("Error: for period parameter, we only have 2, 4, 6, 8,10. Choose one of these values");
}
```

Later on, the `period` parameter is used a form like this (from Github):

```js
var exampleList = ee.List([0.001, 0.002, 0.003, 0.004, 0.005]);
var exampleValue = exampleList[period];
```

The code could be rewritten easily to get rid of the if-statements, like this for instance:

```js
var period = ee.Number(6);
var periodDict = ee.Dictionary({
  '2':0,
  '4':1,
  '6':2,
  '8':3,
  '10':4,
});
var exampleList = ee.List([0.001, 0.002, 0.003, 0.004, 0.005]);
var exampleValue = exampleList.get(periodDict.get(period.format()));
```

But then I don't know how to retain the opportunity to throw an error when the value for `period` is out of bounds.

How can I check the parameters of a function in Google Earth Engine and throw errors while avoiding if-statements?

Comment: The best way to handle this depends on _where the parameter came from_ (what data source, what code provided it) and what you're doing with it. Can you [edit] your question to say more about that? The right answer might be to use `if` anyway, or something else.

Comment: Hi @KevinReid, thank you for your comment, I have expanded the question now, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing at all wrong with using a JavaScript `if` statement *when it works*. The advice you linked is about using `ee.Algorithms.If` which is unfortunately often inefficient — that's completely unrelated. The usual problem with a JavaScript `if` is when you're trying to use it *on a server-side value that hasn't been computed yet*.

But in your case, it looks like you want to validate a user-provided parameter. `if` is a perfectly fine way to do this.

I'll suggest one improvement: instead of using `alert("error message");`, use `throw new Error`:

```js
  throw new Error("For period parameter, we only have 2, 4, 6, 8,10. Choose one of these values");
```

This has two advantages:

- It doesn't pop a dialog that the user must interact with before fixing the problem, but just results in an error message in the usual place, the Code Editor's Console.
- It will stop the rest of the code from executing, which alert() doesn't.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying both the proper contexts of if-statements, as well as the difference between `throw` and `alert`!